# Confused about chirality of antiparticles and QED interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, spinors, chirality

In the middle of doing some calculations and I seem to have forgotten some basics from QFT. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out!

Taking, for example, an interaction proportional to $\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$, and decomposing each fermion into its left- and right-handed components, I know that certain terms go to zero such as $\overline{\psi_R}\gamma^\mu\psi_L=0$. I don't have any problem showing this; my confusion is a bit more conceptual, I think.

Take the term involving a left-handed fermion and a right-handed antifermion, $\overline{\psi_L}\gamma^\mu\psi_L$. The $\overline{\psi_L}$ is right-handed, isn't it? Otherwise in EW interactions we would have helicity violation. However, when I expand it out and do the algebra, I find

$$
\overline{\psi_L} = \overline{\frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5)\psi} = \bar{\psi}P_R
$$

where $P_R$ is on the right due to the conjugation. Can I take it to mean, then, that $P_R$ operates on $\bar{\psi}$ to the *left* to produce a right-handed antiparticle? I recall seeing something like this in the Dirac equation, but I was unsure of it back then, too.

I know it's simple, but I have the feeling there's something fundamental I'm not understanding.

Comment: Yes, you have it: a $W^-$ decays to a left-handed muon and a right-handed antineutrino, among others.

Comment: The terms left/right-handed are used for two different things: chirality, which is a field thing, and helicity, which is a particle thing. Sometimes people use the terms left/right-handed without saying whether they mean chirality or helicity, and sometimes people use the word particle as a synonym for field. It's like a non-deliberate form of encryption, sometimes even more unbreakable than RSA. Are the distinctions between chirality/helicity or between field/particle relevant to what you're asking?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I don't think so, as I'm considering the high-energy limit. I'm more just wondering about my algebra that a RH antiparticle is given by $\bar{\psi} P_R$

Comment: Your algebra is correct, but I'm not sure what you mean by right-handed antiparticle. Are you asking if applying the operator $\overline\psi P_R$ to the vacuum state would give a state with a single right-handed antiparticle (in a theory with no interactions, for simplicity)?